# curl follow location error

Tags: curl, php

I got this error message:

> CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in.

safe_mode is turned off on my web hosting.

open_basedir is "".

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You can easily extract the referred site link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520085/669677

Comment: here answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6918742/2165415

Answer (score 12):

The workaround is to implement redirection in PHP code.

Here is my own implementation. It has two known limitations:

1. It will force `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`
2. It is incompatible with `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`

The code:

```
function curl_exec_follow(/*resource*/ &$ch, /*int*/ $redirects = 20, /*bool*/ $curlopt_header = false) {
    if ((!ini_get('open_basedir') && !ini_get('safe_mode')) || $redirects < 1) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $curlopt_header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $redirects > 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $redirects);
        return curl_exec($ch);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);

        do {
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch))
                break;
            $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if ($code != 301 && $code != 302)
                break;
            $header_start = strpos($data, "\r\n")+2;
            $headers = substr($data, $header_start, strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n", $header_start)+2-$header_start);
            if (!preg_match("!\r\n(?:Location|URI): *(.*?) *\r\n!", $headers, $matches))
                break;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $matches[1]);
        } while (--$redirects);
        if (!$redirects)
            trigger_error('Too many redirects. When following redirects, libcurl hit the maximum amount.', E_USER_WARNING);
        if (!$curlopt_header)
            $data = substr($data, strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n")+4);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I  needed to add `&& $code!=303` (See Other) to the if condition in the do-loop to replicate my `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=true` behaviour.

Comment: Related blog-post [cURL: follow locations with safe_mode enabled or open_basedir set (31 Mar 2012 by Slopjong)](http://slopjong.de/2012/03/31/curl-follow-locations-with-safe_mode-enabled-or-open_basedir-set/) - it's also not perfect, but maybe of help if someone wants to review the codes.

Answer (score 5):

The only place where this warning message is printed is in ext/curl/interface.c

```
if ((PG(open_basedir) && *PG(open_basedir)) || PG(safe_mode)) {
  if (Z_LVAL_PP(zvalue) != 0) {
    php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set");
    RETVAL_FALSE;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

As you can see from the if-condition either open_basedir or safe_mode must be enabled.

Comment: is there any way to overcome this?
like a custom follow location function or something similar

Comment: You can use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` and if it returns 301 or 302 fetch the Location: header.

Comment: this is zsalab's implementation

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar situation a while back and found the solution below.  If you know generally where you'll be redirected to this might work for you.

```
    function curl($url, $postVars)
{
    $go = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($go, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($go, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    //follow on location problems
    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off'))
    {
        curl_setopt ($go, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $l);
        $syn = curl_exec($go);
        if(curl_error($go))
            return false;
    }
    else
        $syn = curl_redir_exec($go, $postVars);
    curl_close($go);
    return $syn;
}

function curl_redir_exec($ch, $postVars)
{
    static $curl_loops = 0;
    static $curl_max_loops = 20;
    if ($curl_loops++>= $curl_max_loops)
    {
        $curl_loops = 0;
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch))
        return false;
    list($header, $data) = explode("\n\r", $data, 2);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $redirect_page = "[0-9]*.html";
    $base_redirect = "http://example.com/";

    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302)
    {
        $matches = array();
        $pregs = eregi($redirect_page, $data, $matches);
        $new_url = $base_redirect . $matches[0];
        if (!$new_url)
        {
            //couldn't process the url to redirect to
            $curl_loops = 0;
            return $data;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);

        return curl_redir_exec($ch, $postVars);
    }
    else
    {
        $curl_loops=0;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never tested in real environment but has more transparency with curl_exec (no problem with header and returntransfer options).

```
function curl_exec_follow(/*resource*/ $ch, /*int*/ $maxredirect = 5) {
    if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '' && ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        $newurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

        $rch = curl_copy_handle($ch);
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        do {
            curl_setopt($rch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
            $header = curl_exec($rch);
            if (curl_errno($rch)) {
                $code = 0;
            } else {
                $code = curl_getinfo($rch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                if ($code == 301 || $code == 302) {
                    preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
                    $newurl = trim(array_pop($matches));
                } else {
                    $code = 0;
                }
            }
        } while ($code && $maxredirect--);
        curl_close($rch);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $newurl);
    }
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: This implementation has two problems: 1. if an error occurs, it will be lost; 2. the request of the final URL is done twice (one just for headers, one full)

Comment: `ini_get('safe_mode' == 'Off')` Typo (parentheses should enclose 'safe_mode', and won't work everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

Just a note:

All answers with code here manually parse the headers from a curl request to find a `Location:` header.

However, since PHP 5.3.7, there is an option `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL` you can use with `curl_getinfo()`. No need to do requests twice, no need to enable headers if you don't want them, no need for regexps.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a `$curl` instance already configured and just want to simulate `curl_exec` with FOLLOWLOCATION enabled, you can use this one:

```
function curl_follow_exec($curl, $url = null)
{
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    if (!is_null($url))
    {
        $opts = array (
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_POST => false,
            CURLOPT_PUT => false,
        );
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);
    }
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $arr = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data);
    while (strpos(reset($arr), 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue') !== false)
    {
        array_shift($arr);
    }
    $header = $arr[0];
    $body = implode("\r\n", array_slice($arr, 1));
    if ($status['http_code'] == 301 || $status['http_code'] == 302)
    {
        $matches = array ();
        preg_match("/(Location:|URI:)[^(\n)]*/", $header, $matches);
        $url = trim(str_replace($matches[1], "", $matches[0]));
        return curl_follow_exec($curl, $url);
    }
    return $body;
}
```

Note: don't provide an URL when calling this function if you already specified the option, it is just used for recursive purposes.

I inspired this code from the accepted answer, and added some stuffs to manage multiple headers.

This function is like an ugly hack for ie6: if you can, change your hosting :-).