# PHP CURL follow redirect to get HTTP status

Tags: php, redirect, curl, http-status-code-301

I created the following PHP function to the HTTP code of a webpage.

```
function get_link_status($url, $timeout = 10) 
{
  $ch = curl_init();

  // set cURL options
  $opts = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // do not output to browser
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,            // set URL
                CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,         // do a HEAD request only
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout);   // set timeout
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);

  curl_exec($ch); // do it!

  $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // find HTTP status

  curl_close($ch); // close handle

  return $status;
}
```

How can I modify this function to follow 301 & 302 redirects (possibility multiple redirects) and get the final HTTP status code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make curl follow redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Answer (score 18):

set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `TRUE`.

```
$opts = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // do not output to browser
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,            // set URL
                CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,         // do a HEAD request only
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true  // follow location headers
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout);   // set timeout
```

If you're not bound to curl, you can do this with standard PHP http wrappers as well (which might be even curl then internally). Example code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$code = FALSE;

$options['http'] = array(
    'method' => "HEAD"
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$body = file_get_contents($url, NULL, $context);

foreach($http_response_header as $header)
{
    sscanf($header, 'HTTP/%*d.%*d %d', $code);
}

echo "Status code (after all redirects): $code<br>\n";
```

See as well [HEAD first with PHP Streams](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/).

A related question is [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php).

Comment: great answer. in my case i needed the final location, so doing a `sscanf($header, 'Location: %s', $loc);` did the trick. thank you!