# Find url and get ip address of website after redirect

Tags: php, url, ip-address, http-redirect

If I have :

**domainA.com/out.php :**

```
<?php
  header('location: http://domainB.com/');
?>
```

Is it possible to get url : `domainB.com` and it's `IP Address`, with `domanA.com/out.php` from `domainC.com`?

*What I want :*

**domainA.com/index.php**

```
<?php
   $data = getUrlandIp("domainA.com/out.php");
   echo $data[0];  # wanted output (URL) : domainB.com
   echo $data[1];  # wanted output (IP) : 133.133.133.133
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681915/php-curl-follow-redirect-to-get-http-status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to get all the redirects, you can do

```
function getRedirectsToUri($uri)
{
    $redirects = array();
    $http = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_params(
        $http,
        array(
            "notification" => function() use (&$redirects)
            {
                if (func_get_arg(0) === STREAM_NOTIFY_REDIRECTED) {
                    $redirects[] = func_get_arg(2);
                }
            }
        )
    );
    file_get_contents($uri, false, $http);
    return $redirects;
}
```

This will return an array holding all the redirects with the last entry being the final destination.

#### Example ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bf8HTj))

```
print_r(getRedirectsToUri('http://bit.ly/VDcn'));
```

#### Output

```
Array ( 
    [0] => http://example.com/ 
    [1] => http://www.iana.org/domains/example/ 
)
```

You'd have to lookup the IP's manually though (see other answers here) but note that a redirect target doesnt have to be a hostname. It can very well be an IP as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) to get the http headers from a URL.

Something like this should work to get the domain name.

```
$headers = get_headers('http://domaina.com/out.php', 1);
echo $headers['Location'];
```

To resolve the IP address, look at the [gethostbyname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) function.

```
echo gethostbyname($headers['Location']);
```

Comment: in my case there is no Header named "Location"

Comment: Maybe it's lowercase `location`? Do a `print_r($headers);` to get a look at everything $headers contains.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by

> from domainC.com?

but in PHP you can call `gethostbyname('domainB.com')` which will give you the IP of domainB.com from `domainA.com/out.php`