# Logging in to Channel Advisor

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to channel advisor but it output an error of: `HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`.

But last week it runs perfectly that I login and retrieve my data and now I run again it has an error.

Here is my code:

```
 $pages = array('home' => 
 'https://login.channeladvisor.com/?gotourl=https%3a%2f%2fcomplete.channeladvisor.com%2f', 
           'login' => 
 'https://login.channeladvisor.com/?gotourl=https%3a%2f%2fcomplete.channeladvisor.com%2f', 
           'data' => 
  'https://merchant.channeladvisor.com/AM/MyInventory/View_Inventory.aspx?apid=32001263'); 

  $ch = curl_init(); 
  //Set options for curl session 
  $options = array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/12.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)', 
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, 
         CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2, 
         CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE, 
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
         CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookies.txt', 
         CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt'); 

//Hit home page for session cookie 
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $pages['home']; 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 
//curl_exec($ch); 

//Login 
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $pages['login']; 
$options[CURLOPT_POST] = TRUE; 
$options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = 'username=xxxxx@gmail.com&password=xxxxxxx'; 
$options[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = false;
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);

//Hit data page 
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = $pages['data'];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 

//Output data
echo $data; 

//Close curl session 
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for data from 'https://merchant.channeladvisor.com/AM/MyInventory/View_Inventory.aspx' Why not use the API instead?

http://developer.channeladvisor.com/display/cadn/Inventory+Service

Answer (score 0):

If exporting your inventory information is all you're trying to do, ChannelAdvisor has its own UI-available inventory export service. At very least, you can automate your code to kick that off and download the exported csv or tab delim file: http://ssc.channeladvisor.com/howto/exporting-inventory

Answer (score -1):

I think you should handle such update from Channel Advisor and so, follow the redirect.

Since I don't think this is a common way to login to Channel Advisor using curl, you will always need to update your code on each Channel Advisor update. *It remember me when we can only use curl to retrieve Google Analytics data: every time they update the login system, you have to rewrite your own curl login method - boring*.

You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520085/569101) about following a `Header: Location` with curl. Basically:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r))
 $l = trim($r[1]);
```