# cURL problems with PHP

Tags: php, curl

Previosly I have been pulling in some page content via CURL from the BBC site using this code,

```
    $c = curl_init('http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/football/eng_conf/conference_north_table/default.stm');

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $html =  curl_exec ($c);
    if (curl_error($c))
        die(curl_error($c));

    $startpos = strpos($html, '<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" class="fulltable">');

    $endpos = strpos($html, '<!-- E IINC -->');
    $length = $endpos - $startpos;
    $rest = substr($html, $startpos,$length);
    $rest = str_replace("border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\"","border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"", $rest);
    $rest = str_replace('<tr><td colspan="15"><hr/></td></tr>',"", $rest);

    $rest = str_replace('<tr>
      <td colspan="15">
         <div style="padding: 10px 0 0 0;"><img src=" http://newsimg.bbc.co.uk/sol/shared/img/tbl_spc.gif" height="2px" width="100%"></div>
      </td>
   </tr>
',"", $rest);

    echo $rest;
    curl_close($c);
```

Previously this was working fine using php 5.1.3 on an **old** server we have since migrated the site to a server running 5.4.8, however the above code is not working anymore, is there any reason for this? I cannot see any problem.

If I kill the script at `$html` I get the following reponse,

> LEAGUE TABLE
>
> MOVED PERMANENTLY
>
> The document has moved here.

However if I navigate to the URL through the browser I can view the page fine, so it obviously has not moved anywhere (backed up by the fact the Curl request was working before we migrated servers.

Comment: Any error messages? Have you inserted debug statements to see what the values look like? What exactly does "not working anymore" mean?

Comment: good habit to **always** put block code in `{}` brackets. Even one liners like in your case `if (curl_error($c)) ....` - Such habit would save your from troubles in less expected moment

Comment: It may be trying to redirect to another page and not following through. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects ?

Comment: try curl_info() to see any information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address has actually moved. Change the first line with:

```
$c = curl_init('http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/eng_conf/conference_north_table/default.stm');
```

The above code now shows me the table with the results.

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

to follow the redirection.

See [PHP: curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for the full list of options.