# File_get_contents() not working when the get url redirects

Tags: php, file-get-contents

The function I am using is:

```
function http_post ($url, $data)
{
$data_url = http_build_query ($data);
$data_len = strlen ($data_url);
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

return array ('content'=>file_get_contents ($url, false
    , stream_context_create (array ('http'=>array (
    'method'=>'GET', 
    'header'=>"Connection: close\r\nContent-Length: $data_len\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", 
    'content'=>$data_url
    )))), 
    'headers'=>$http_response_header
    );
}
```

And the call is:

```
http_post('http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast/', array('airportorwmo'=>'query','historytype'=>'DailyHistory','backurl'=>"/history/index.html",'code'=>"$myCode",'month'=>"$myMonth",'day'=>"$myDay",'year'=>"$myYear"));
```

The original form is located on the following page, but I'm using the form's action page in the call:

```
wunderground.com/history/
```

Ultimately I want to get contents from the redirected page, which is for example:

```
http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/CWTA/2013/1/24/DailyHistory.html?req_city=McTavish&req_state=QC&req_statename=Quebec&MR=1
```

However as above, the form takes different elements, i.e. code, month, day, year.

Comment: Try curl: [Make curl follow redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Comment: This should work if I am not mistaken as [this](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.follow-location) says the default value is to follow redirects. Unless `max_redirects` is being reached or it is timing out.

Answer (score 4):

Why not [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

```
function http_post ($url, $data)
{
    $data_url = http_build_query ($data);
    $data_len = strlen ($data_url);
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array(array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    ));

    $content = curl_exec();

    curl_close($curl);

    return array (
        'content' => $content,
        'headers' => $http_response_header,
    );

 }
```

Also, your function is named `post` but you are doing `GET` request

Comment: I'm making some adjustments, but it looks like it will work, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

try below function

```
function http_post ($url, $data)
{
    $data_url = http_build_query ($data);
    $data_len = strlen ($data_url);
   date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

   return array ('content'=>file_get_contents ($url, true
, stream_context_create (array ('http'=>array (
'method'=>'GET', 
'header'=>"Connection: close\r\nContent-Length: $data_len\r\nContent-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", 
'content'=>$data_url
)))), 
'headers'=>$http_response_header
);

 }
```

Comment: Huh? All you did as far as I can see is change the boolean value for the 2nd argument to `true` if you read the [documentation](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-parameters) that just toggles searching in the include path or not.

Comment: thanks @crypticツ . yes only change in boolean part. I have executed the code and it is working fine. weather api is returning the perfect result.