# Getting the URL of redirected page - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have this URL to which I'm trying to redirected the page:
http://www.hotukdeals.com/visit?m=1650&q=1542029

I already tried:

```
$ch1 = curl_init("http://www.hotukdeals.com/visit?m=1650&q=1542029"); 
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    curl_exec($ch1);
    $curl_url = curl_getinfo($ch1, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    echo $curl_url;
```

I'm getting this response, which is the same URL:

> http://www.hotukdeals.com/visit?m=1650&q=1542029

How can I get this to work?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Answer (score 0):

This should work in most cases, unless the redirect is made with Javascript.

```
print_r(get_headers('http://www.hotukdeals.com/visit?m=1650&q=1542029'));
```