# cURL GET Request Returns No Output

Tags: curl

I'm sending a simple `curl` request to `pinterest.com`. When I do it using `PHP` no result is shown. I tried it from command line and no result showed up. Then I tried the verbose mode in `curl` and it gives:

```
curl 7.27.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.27.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: Debug GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

I have searched but could not sort out. What am I doing wrong?

The command is:

```
curl -v pinterest.com
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Check the headers: It's only accessible by https:

```
$ curl --dump-header - http://pinterest.com/
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 19:25:49 GMT
Etag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
Location: https://pinterest.com/
Pinterest-Breed: CORGI
Pinterest-Generated-By: ngapp-b7f64694
Pinterest-Version: a8eef3c
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=A2VQZGarr509JKxrJxiuW2MbrXNdHlUH; Domain=.pinterest.com; expires=Thu, 17-Jul-2014 19:25:49 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: _pinterest_sess="eJwz84isyvfJcilP1S4szHY20A6MKitJKwwPdi+2tY8vycxNtfUN8TX2c3E19gsJNfAPtLVVK04tLs5MsfXMcjTxq/KsAGJj3/CgHL+QoGzfrLCMSKNAIz93X+PIrHQTIF0eFe6X4ZluawsAh3UjNA=="; Domain=.pinterest.com; expires=Sun, 13-Jul-2014 19:25:49 GMT; Max-Age=31103999; Path=/
Vary: Cookie
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-Varnish: 1991078486
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

If you use the `-L` option you'll get the page:

```
$ curl -L http://pinterest.com/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html lang="en" class="ie7 ielt9 ielt10 en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html lang="en" class="ie8 ielt9 ielt10 en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html lang="en" class="ie9 ielt10 en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en" class=" en"><!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <script>
[snip]
```

Here in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects) is how it's done with PHP:

[Years later...] also, `-V` is `--version`, not `--verbose`, which is lowercase `-v`. invoking `curl -V` causes it to display the version and *ignore any args*, so you would never get the page that way anyway.

Comment: It gives me 

:~$ curl -D http://pinterest.com/
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Any suggestions? \

Comment: borked my cut-and-paste. will fix momentarily.

Comment: -D requires an arg, which can be '-' for stdout. I noticed a bunch of problem with my cut-and-paste but didn't catch that one. sorry about that.

Answer (score 12):

It could be a problem with the target site URL doing a redirect.

By default, when curl receives a redirect after making a request, it won't make a request to the new URL. As an example of this, consider the URL http://www.facebook.com. When you make a request using to this URL, the server sends a HTTP 3XX redirect to https://www.facebook.com/. If you try the following you will get an empty output:

$ curl http://www.facebook.com
$
If you want cURL to follow these redirects, you should use the -L option.

$ curl -L http://www.facebook.com/

You could try it out with pinterest.com for your example.
Compare the output of "curl pinterest.com" with "curl -L pinterest.com"