# how to do curl php redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Is there a way to do redirect in PHP using curl? I looked some examples but none of them works in my case. I need to login to url1, then redirect me to url2. (url_1 is the site of my IP camera, url_2 is my page which contains the iframe of url_1, in order to see the content of url_1 in my page, authentication is required)

Please check my code and tell me where I did wrong, many thanks!

```
<?
$url = 'url_1';
$username = 'admin';
$password = '888888';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "url_2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

$a = curl_exec($ch);


$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
print_r($info);

$headers = explode("\n",$a);
$redir = $url;
// loop through the headers and check for a Location: str
$j = count($headers);
for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++){
// if we find the Location header strip it and fill the redir var       
if(strpos($headers[$i],"Location:") !== false){
        $redir = trim(str_replace("Location:","",$headers[$i]));
        break;
    }
}
// do whatever you want with the result
echo $redir;
?>
```

I also print the $info here:

```
Array ( 
[url] => url_1
[content_type] => text/html 
[http_code] => 200 
[header_size] => 180 
[request_size] => 288 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 0.016 
[namelookup_time] => 0 
[connect_time] => 0 
[pretransfer_time] => 0 
[size_upload] => 0 
[size_download] => 6379 
[speed_download] => 398687 
[speed_upload] => 0 
[download_content_length] => 6379 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 0.016 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
)
```

and the $redir is:url_1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make curl follow redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Comment: You've already got the `FOLLOWLOCATION` enabled, so curl will follow any redirects that the server it's hitting happens to issue.

Comment: @ Marc B so setting FOLLOWLOCATION to false will fix the issue? I tried and it didnt work

Comment: @HughH: Enabled doesn't mean `false`. It means `set it to TRUE`.

Comment: @AmalMurali I think I know that.. it doesnt work when it is set to TRUE

Comment: I believe the OP wants to redirect **the user** to another page using curl (and not making curl follow redirects). And AFAIK such thing is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing different topics here. If you issue a curl request on the server side, nothing will happen to the logged in client. If you want to redirect a logged in client to somewhere, you need to issue a HTTP Redirect header. That will happen with

```
Header("Location: http://domain.com/page.php");
```

directive. Nothing to do with curl as such.

You can however first do a request with curl to another resource (such as your url1) and then use PHP to issue a redirect to url2, containing your iframe. Something like `Header("Location: $redir");` in your code.