# Read a remote file in php

Tags: php

I want to show contents of a remote file (a file on another server) on my website.

I used the following code, readfile() function is working fine on the current server

```
<?php
echo readfile("editor.php");
```

But when I tried to get a remote file

```
<?php
echo readfile("http://example.com/php_editor.php");
```

It showed the following error :

**301 moved**

The document has moved [here](http://example.com/php_editor.php) 224

I am getting this error remote files only, local files are showing with no problem.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use curl instead of `readfile()`, and configure it with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` so it handles the redirect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: A more direct example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects

Comment: @Starkeen do you see that you can't  *show contents of a remote file* but only result of execution

Comment: can't you just use file_get_contents?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Option 1 - Curl**

Use CURL and set the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`-option to true:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http//example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === FALSE) {
         echo "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
    } else {
         echo curl_exec($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

**Option 2 - file_get_contents**

According to the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will follow up to 20 redirects as default. Therefore you could use that function. On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE and otherwise it will return the entire file.

```
<?php

    $string = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");

    if($string === FALSE) {
         echo "Could not read the file.";
    } else {
         echo $string;
    }

?>
```

Comment: It would be good to mention that OP should really check `file_get_contents` result for errors like: `if($string===FALSE) { $string = "Could not load file!"; }` and also do the same for curl's errors.

Comment: Thank you! I have added the information in my post.

Comment: Don't forget, that for "Option 2" the configuration variable 'allow_url_fopen' must be set to on.