# file-get-contents returning false for localhost

Tags: curl, localhost, file-get-contents, drupal-9

I'm mworking on a Drupal site for which I need to export page content into PDFs. The URLs generating the pdfs are all working correctly but when I attempt to use the *file_get_contents* function to retrieve the page contents from **http://localhost:81/export/58/pdf**, it returns **false** indicating a failure of the function.

Similarly, I attempted using *curl* following examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572189/read-a-remote-file-in-php) but I encounted similar issues i:e the generated pdfs where entirely empty.

I then tried a random url off the internet and I was able to get results using *curl* and *file_get_contents*.

Googling a lot, I found posts indicating **allow_url_fopen** needs to be **ON** (which it was), **openssl** needs to be enabled (which it was). Also, there was a post about a firewall potentially blocking things. I disabled the Windows Firewall but things still have not changed.

The potential added complication is that my Drupal site that the Drupal site is being powered from Docker. I'm not sure how that might be affecting things.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out my suspicions were correct, it was very much a Docker complication.

My mistake was attempting to `curl localhost` from within my docker container. The container can not relate to **localhost or 127.0.0.1**.

The solution was to find the containers internal IP address by running:

```
ip -4 -o address
```

The resulting IP address when called with curl and replacing localhost then successfully downloaded my page content, i:e :

```
curl http://172.20.0.7/export/export/58/pdf
```