# PHP cURL retrieving response headers AND body in a single request in case of request?

Tags: curl

I have a site, which redirects to another url. I used this solution: [Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request) but it returns an empty string for "body" because the called url has redirection. How to get the content after redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these links can help you:

- [Make curl follow redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)
- http://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/