# handle API that has redirect response

Tags: php, rest, redirect, curl

I had a case, I need to post data to API end point that has redirect response, i mean when i hit for example "xxx.com/api/v1/receive" with several post parameters, its suppose to redirect to a page that handle authentication provided by API provider for further access, then redirect back to my site.

in my code i implement something like this to post data

```
$data = ['key'=>'val'.etc...];
$post_data = http_build_query($data);

// open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// set option
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->dev_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);


// execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

when i use regular form submit using html form and post some parameters its run with redirect stuff like its suppose to do , but when i post data like my code above, it has no response. Is it possible to get response (redirect response) like html form using curl?

Comment: So when your form action was the endpoint, script executed as expected, but when using CURL and changing action to self, script didn't work as intended?

Comment: Also remember to set CURLOPT_POST to true

Comment: correct. i just set CURLOPT_POST true, still no response

Comment: Try also setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true. If you have access to the API endpoint, you can also put a die('QA') or return 'QA'; as first line to give some clue as to something inside the API script failing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make curl follow redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Comment: Thanks,  i follow the link and try the code, still has no response, what im thinking right now is using html form and set parameters as input type hidden

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = ['key'=>'val'.etc...];

$result = file_get_contents ( "http://yoururl.com", false, stream_context_create ( array (
                    'http' => array (
                            'method' => 'POST',
                            'content' => json_encode ( $data ) 
                    ))));
```

you can check the `var_dump($result);`

Comment: i've got this error "file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded"