# Login to website and get the redirected url content with PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the content (text) from a website where I am a member, I found a plenty of examples of how to do this using cURL to login and get the context, however I am not sure how to handle with the redirection after I get log into the website. The result that I got from the code below is the login form ([Example #1 here][1]). I am wondering if I have no access is this really possible to do?

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
    'Account' => 'myaccount',
    'Password' => 'mypass'
    )
 );

$opts = array('http' =>
        array(
         'method'  => 'POST',
         'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'content' => $postdata
    )
  );

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://www.website.php/login.php', false, 
$context);
```

After the login successful what I expect is to get the text from the redirected url which looks like http://www.website.php/other.php
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make curl follow redirects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)