# simple cURL not working

Tags: php, curl

I have code here that *should* return to me the source code of the webpage.

```
<?php
function curlGet($url){
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  $results = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

}

$packtPage = curlGet('https://www.google.com');

print_r($packtPage);
```

As far as I understand this code should return and echo out the source code of that webpage. However, I get a blank page when running this code.

After searching everywhere for an understanding of why this isn't working as expected I troubleshooted and found that commenting out the following line

```
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

the webpage shows

```
302 Moved

The document has moved here.
```

'here' is a link that redirects to the url that was given.

Please help me understand what's going on!!

Comment: add a return statement at the end of your function

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you may also want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Comment: @GentlemanMax I'll add that to my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
```

You are telling PHP to "Store the output of the cURL request in the `$results` variable and don't output anything to the screen.

If you want to see output, modify your code as following to return the value of `$results` to the print_r function:

```
<?php
function curlGet($url){
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  $results = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  return $results;
}

$packtPage = curlGet('https://www.google.com');

print_r($packtPage);
```

As suggested by GentlemanMax in a comment, it can also be a good idea to include the following line in your cURL request. This line tells cURL to follow redirects, since you are receiving a `HTTP/302` status code which means the page was moved. Curl can follow these kind of redirects using the following extra option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: yes. thank you. I forgot to add the return statement at the end. But it was really the 302 redirects that was troubling me a bit. Also it was confusing that when troubleshooting instead of echo I tried var_dump or print_r and the same result was appearing. But now I understand more so thank you for the answer. It helped me in my first foray into cURL!