# CURL gives HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: php, redirect, curl, cookies, http-status-code-302

CURL gives HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily

```
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://...........");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'));
$result = curl_exec($ch1);
```

**Output:**

> HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive Date: Mon, 03 Jul 2017
>   12:23:55 GMT
>   Set-Cookie:AWSALB=ZBxF0OO7JHWtHtsbAUVLo1a2Y7GQ1KTxIaMml+1UFTDK2UL7V6Xm8FIU1mWeCDZDtYvQ0emHLPLOtWpli
>   +6pqFbYe+ulWPA8SBqeM/n5S9x0ScxYTGVsUeDixyuf; Expires=Mon, 10 Jul 2017 12:23:55 GMT; Path=/ Server: nginx/1.8.0 Location:
>   https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx X-Cache: Miss
>   from cloudfront Via: 1.1
>   ea5d711fdce750991b725e09c07704b0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
>   X-Amz-Cf-Id: rVytkGKHVM628Zh3WFSohHlVdb-6XXZX-cXlQkvtRSeDCZN95s9Guw==

Comment: Set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true if you want to follow redirects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make curl follow redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects)

Comment: i have already used but same result

Comment: You used `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false` FALSE means dont follow. `TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).` -http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: If i am going to set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); then it gives **"HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"** after **HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily**

Comment: The answer to the question you asked though is the dup. You should update the code and the question in that case.