# Download file to server PHP

Tags: php, curl, roblox

The file I am trying to download is located here

```
https://assetgame.roblox.com/Asset/?id=942531514
```

When you load the link, it auto forces a download on you.

I'm trying to find a way to make PHP download the file and store it on the server for later use.

I've tried Curl and file_put_contents of file_get_contents, but neither have worked.

Thanks!

Comment: I've clicked the link in chrome, it doesn't force a download. It is simply a json_encoded array. Curl or file_get_contents should work, and when coupled with json_decode you should be fine with getting the data.

Comment: My bad, updated the post.  I accidentally put the wrong link, my bad.

Comment: Sorry Lawrence, I accidentally put the wrong URL.  I'd like the file, not the XML.

Answer (score 1):

your url use a [HTTP Location Redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location), which file_get_contents does not understand at all, which is why file_get_contents definitely won't work (warning, another reason file_get_contents might fail is because of the `allow_url_fopen` php.ini setting). curl does understand it, but ignores it by default, that's probably why your curl code failed. explicitly tell curl to follow http redirects with the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`option, and it should work with curl, eg

```
$ch = curl_init ( 'https://assetgame.roblox.com/Asset/?id=942531514' );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
) );
$xml=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the breakdown.

The url you are trying to call : `https://assetgame.roblox.com/Asset/?id=942531514`

The url the file is located at: `http://c3.rbxcdn.com/43865ade81ebad6d3493166f3bcfc631`

Since the server is returning a forced download in the header. You can try something like this:

```
function download_file($url,$saveto){
    $cinit = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($cinit, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($cinit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($cinit, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $cexec=curl_exec($cint);
    curl_close ($cinit);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: How would I go about getting the second image url from the first url?

Comment: I hope [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/how-can-i-find-where-i-will-be-redirected-using-curl) might be helpful for that task