# How to get actual image URL?

Tags: php, image, curl

I have below remote URL

```
http://cdn.amazon.com/picture/f184a6f7b9c4371cf962537ff384a362d97aa495044995079bca063aeb66d8c0
```

When I copy/paste this URL in browser then it gives me

```
http://cdn.amazon.com/picture/logo
```

How to get above URL? I want to compare with this browser URL & process the functionality.

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Working on PHP. So need to find solution on that.

Comment: The remote URL you've mentioned is not publicly accessible and returns a site can't be reached. Are you sure that the image link is correct?

Comment: It's sample image URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get actual URL from the PHP (I hope you are asking it)

Default PHP `file_get_contents` method doesn't want to wait for redirects. It means if you are asking some URL which has a redirect, PHP doesn't follow this redirect and waiting for a final content.

You can use cURL with "Follow Redirect params": https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520085/2552784

Or use [guzzlehttp/guzzle](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle). It is a very good PSR-7 wrapper of the cURL library.