# How to get content of a webpage that is redirecting to another page?

Tags: php

I use `file_get_contents` to get the content of a webpage,

```
$urlContent = file_get_contents('http://some.tld');
```

this webpage redirects to another page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://some.tld/123">
```

What I need is the URL it is directing to. Here it would be **http://some.tld/123**

It seems `file_get_contents` is waiting to be redirected and gets the content of the new site.

Comment: If you can use cURL instead, then you can [check this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520085/2453432) for an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find where I will be redirected using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/how-can-i-find-where-i-will-be-redirected-using-curl)