# How to get response after third party url redirection in PHP with curl

Tags: php, php-curl

How to get response after third party url redirection in PHP with curl?

```php
function curlRequest($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    return $result; 
}
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to true will instruct cURL to follow redirects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/how-can-i-find-where-i-will-be-redirected-using-curl

Comment: Dear Maksim ,I have a unique URL which is redirect any other URL For Example :- i open http://localhost:8080/Code-Diffusion/analistic/XzQwWQRfA.php?p_id=ABCD2&ID=4564 and i dont know where this url(another Website,another server,another country) will redirect ,so how can i get ending url status

Answer (score 0):

curl_test_redirect.php

```php
<?php

function curlRequest($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); 

    return $result; 
}

echo curlRequest('http://localhost//myWork/testPHP/curl_first_hit.php');
?>
```

curl_first_hit.php

```
<?php
echo 'hello in first hit';
header('Location: http://localhost//myWork/testPHP/curl_second_hit.php');
?>
```

curl_second_hit.php

```
<?php
echo 'hello in second hit';
?>
```

Comment: Dear Raja vikraman,I have a unique URL which is redirect any other URL For Example :- i open localhost:8080/Code-Diffusion/analistic/… and i dont know where this url(another Website,another server,another country) will redirect ,so how can i get ending url status