# PHP - Get final url from a url after all redirections (curl + php)

Tags: php, curl

```
// From URL to get redirected URL
$url = 'https://www.shareasale.com/m-pr.cfm?merchantID=83483&userID=1860618&productID=916465625';
  
$ch = curl_init(); // create cURL handle (ch)
if (!$ch) {
    die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
}
// set some cURL options
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         1);
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ret = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        30);

// execute
$ret = curl_exec($ch);

if (!empty($ret)) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
    if (empty($info['http_code'])) {
            die("No HTTP code was returned");
    } else {
        echo 'REDIRECTED FINAL URL'.$info['url']); // this does not give final url.
    }

}
```

is their any way we can get final url from a url after all re-directions ?
Let me know if any changes needs to be done in this code ?

https://www.shareasale.com/m-pr.cfm?merchantID=83483&userID=1860618&productID=916465625

This is the url which has lots of redirections, i am testing code with this one but it does not return final url, it return some the url then the url which you see in url bar.

Comment: From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php, does `$info['redirect_url']` give anything different? Or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/28458522/1213708?

Comment: $info['redirect_url'] returns blank

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/28458522/1213708 did'nt help

Comment: There must be something that can help

Comment: @NigelRen What you say ?

Comment: https://www.shareasale.com/m-pr.cfm?merchantID=83483&userID=1860618&productID=916465625

This is the url which has lots of redirections, i am testing code with this one but it does not return final url, it return some the url then the url which you see in url bar.

Comment: I've just tried your code and it gives `REDIRECTED FINAL URLhttps://www.shareasale-analytics.com/m-pr.cfm?merchantID=83483&userID=1860618&productID=916465625&shrsl_analytics_sscid=71k5%5F2zo0q&shrsl_analytics_sstid=71k5%5F2zo0q`, which is different to the start url.  Not sure what it's supposed to be so not sure what else to do.

Comment: @NigelRen is should be the url which we get on url bar when we directly access the url.

I found that it uses "  window.location.replace('https:\/\/loomyhome.com\/collections\/all-products\/products\/blue-my-mind-rug?sscid=71k5_2zvjg&')
" to redirect & this is the final url i,e (loomyhome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have is working correctly, but it is only part of what you want.  When you get to the final URL redirect, your return includes...

```
<HTML><head></head><body>

    
        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">
        window.location.replace('https:\/\/loomyhome.com\/collections\/all-products\/products\/blue-my-mind-rug?sscid=71k5_300lf&')
        </script>
    

</body></html>
```

So you then need to extract the URL from there.  You can use a regex (not my best skill) which would be something like...

```
preg_match('#(https:.*?)\'\)#', $ret, $match);

echo stripslashes($match[1]);
```

(using `stripslashes` to unescape the string).  Gives...

```
https://loomyhome.com/collections/all-products/products/blue-my-mind-rug?sscid=71k5_3097f&
```

Comment: Yes how would we get the "final URL redirect" ?

Comment: If that isn't the final URL, then repeat the CURL process you have in the question with this new URL.