# How To Load And Save Facebook Profile Picture Of User

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I Want direct link of user's profile picture

i Have Following Code

```
    $img = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $fid . "/picture?type=large");
    $file = dirname(__file__). "/" . $fid . ".jpg";
    file_put_contents($file, $img);
```

But `https://graph.facebook.com/" . $fid . "/picture?type=large` Have a Redirection. How do i follow the redirection? is there any way to do it via file_get_contents? I know i can do it via `curl` But It Seems complicated i got error that `safe_mode` is on and i don't know how to off it.

Thanks You

Comment: You may need to disable SSL check.
See this post! http://stackoverflow.com/a/26151993/6168524

Answer (score 1):

You should be able follow redirects with file_get_contents by giving it a third parameter `$context` – in which you set the [HTTP context option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) `follow_location` to 1.

(Although this should already be the default, and in my test getting the image data worked with file_get_contents alone already.)

Answer (score 1):

Her is the code that I am using and it works perfect for me. It also saves the picture to my server so I then have a local url (which can then be posted either back to the same user's profile or to the wall of another user/page/event/etc.) All you have to do is place it in your code where $user has a value and it should work just fine.

```
<?
$uid = $user;


function GetTheImage($linky) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $linky);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    # ADDED LINE:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}



$userpicture = "http://graph.facebook.com/$uid/picture?type=large";

$sourceurl = GetTheImage($userpicture);

$save = fopen("/home/arose/public_html/mydomain.com/tmp/$uid-large.jpg", "w"); //this is name of new file that i save
fwrite($save, $sourceurl);
fclose($save);

?>

<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<img src="./tmp/<? echo $uid; ?>-large.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always I Got This Warning When Using $curl Follow Location

Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set

Comment: See the answer to the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918623/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$fbid=$user_profile['id'];
 $pic = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/picture?type=large");
 $filename = $fbid.".jpg";
$path="images/".$filename;
 file_put_contents($path, $pic);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

function curl_redir_exec($ch)
    {
        static $curl_loops = 0;
        static $curl_max_loops = 20;
        if ($curl_loops++ >= $curl_max_loops)
        {
            $curl_loops = 0;
            return FALSE;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        @list($header, $data) = @explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302)
        {
            $matches = array();
            preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
            $url = @parse_url(trim(array_pop($matches)));
            if (!$url)
            {
                //couldn't process the url to redirect to
                $curl_loops = 0;
                return $data;
            }
            $last_url = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
            if (!$url['scheme'])
                $url['scheme'] = $last_url['scheme'];
            if (!$url['host'])
                $url['host'] = $last_url['host'];
            if (!$url['path'])
                $url['path'] = $last_url['path'];
            $new_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . (@$url['query']?'?'.$url['query']:'');
            return $new_url;
        } else {
            $curl_loops=0;
            return $data;
        }
    }

    function get_right_url($url) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        return curl_redir_exec($curl);
    }

        $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=large';

        $file_handler = fopen('img/avatar/'.$fbid.'.jpg', 'w');
        $curl = curl_init(get_right_url($url));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file_handler);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        fclose($file_handler);
```