# Download HTML of any website and echo it in PHP

Tags: php, html

edited this post, i think my problem was explained wrong:

i want my php page to download the HTML code from any page, and i actualy can expect one, "http://www.lolnexus.com/" and i made this code

```
$nexus= file_get_contents('http://www.lolnexus.com/');

$myFile = "nexus.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $nexus);
fclose($fh);
```

and the result is: this

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
```

### Object moved to [here](http://www.lolnexus.com/?cookieTest=1).

---

if i change my url to other webpage, it works fine.....

thanks for reading

Comment: Please give an example of a website that **doesn't** work.

Comment: I suspect you are getting a redirect screen, but you've not asked cURL to follow redirects. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects).

Comment: thanks for replying :)

>http://www.lolnexus.com/<, thats a exemple, would be nice having all his html on a txt or in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but if you are not needing to POST any data to the page you are requesting the HTML from you could also use the file_get_contents function.

```
$html = file_get_contents('www.google.com');
```

Then the HTML for that site will be stored as text in the $html variable.

**Addendum:**

I have tested the following code and both methods are working:

```
<?php
## Define url to grab
$url = 'http://www.lolnexus.com';

## Method 1: simple file_get_contents
$html = file_get_contents($url);

## Method 2: using cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$html = curl_exec($ch);

## Write output to file.
$fh = fopen('html_output.txt', 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $html);
fclose($fh);

## Output something to the page.
echo 'Done!';
?>
```

Note that when using the cURL method ommitting the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION or setting it to FALSE results in getting the redirect message. oh and comment out method 1 or method 2 depending on which one you want to test.

Comment: well i tried that too,
 #code#$html = file_get_contents('http://www.lolnexus.com/');
 
 echo $html;#code#

#output#: "Object moved to here."

Comment: returns this ##<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>

<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://www.lolnexus.com/?cookieTest=1">here</a>.</h2>

</body></html>
##

Comment: cURL may be the better option for you then with the options set as described by other users to instruct cURL to follow any redirects.  Interestingly though, when I do $html = file_get_contents('http://www.lolnexus.com'); I can write the page source to file with no problems and interrogate it. Is this one of the sites you are having issues with the redirects?.

Comment: yes it is, only in this website

Comment: Its odd that I am not having the same problems. However. The problem is that the page is redirecting you and for whatever reason your scripts are not following the redirect (cURL should handle this with no problems). Could you not simply work out where the page is redirecting you to and use that URL instead to potentially bypass the redirect?  I don't know the full scope of your project but if you are querying the same page(s) this is not a guarantee but could be a very simple solution.

Comment: realy? u have no problem? i am doing from a server..maybe is that...? thats stupid

Comment: u know 1 thing? i just isntalled the xampp on my laptop to be a server and my old and your code works, the only diferente was that i was doing it from a server....what could it be and fix it? i dont want my laptop to be a server xD

Comment: The server that you are having issues on is a shared server by some kind of hosting company? perhaps a re-seller? they often have restrictions in place to patch up / mitigate some security issues which could be the problem you are having. unfortunately if this is the problem there might not be a lot you can do besides purchasing a dedicated server or asking nicely if there is any way they can change the php.ini file (this is doubtful). Anyway, going off topic now. you said that putting in the destination URL solved the problem so great! :)

Comment: yes it is one free hosting service, dang...i need to find a new server...

thanks for help, by the way, that lolnexus.com has some "loading"(1-2seconds) and if i get the html, the info is not there, only after loading ends, there is any way to wait that loading ends and then fetch the data i want?

Answer (score 5):

You must use the option [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

This let's curl follow any redirects issued from the web server.

Comment: thanks for replying,
i just want to take the html code of that page, i dont know what that line does, but i dont want to redirect to that page,  i got some error..,


Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /home/a8466706/public_html/index.php on line 11

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6918623/1741542

Answer (score 0):

In order to have `curl_exec` return the output instead of echoing it, add this one:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```