# OctoberCMS: Error while trying to install a plugin

Tags: php, plugins, installation, octobercms

When I try to install the CGGStudio.Loading plugin (or any other plugin) on OctoberCMS, I get the following error:

> "curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set" on line 233 of /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/october/rain/src/Network/Http.php

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set correct `open_basedir` in your `php.ini`file.

`open_basedir` - it is list of directories, where php can have access to files.

More details in [php docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

On most linux systems `php.ini` is located in `/etc/php5/fpm`, `/etc/php5/cli`, /`etc/php5/cgi`

When You use *Nginx* + *php-fpm*, `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` will be used. And when you run

```
php artisan
```

from console `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` will be used.

Also the [same question] ([CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918623/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated))