# How to interact with XBox API using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to learn how to interact with the unofficial xbox api (xboxapi.com) but I can't seem to figure out how to use it. The documentation is very scarce. This is my most recent (and what i thought best) attempt.

```
<?php
$gamertag = rawurlencode("Major Nelson");

$ch = curl_init("http://www.xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/" . $gamertag);

$headers = array('X-Auth: InsertAuthCodeHere', 'Content-Type: application/json');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); # return into a variable
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers ); # custom headers, see above
$xuid = curl_exec( $ch ); # run!
curl_close($ch);

echo $xuid;


?>
```

Upon running the above I get "301 Moved Permanently". Can anyone see what i am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: all the examples appear to be `https`

Comment: @RamRaider That was a good observation, but it still doesn't work even after changing it to https.

Comment: have you tried `https://xboxapi.com/v2/accountXuid/` rather than `http://www.xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/`? seems the closest

Comment: @RamRaider accountXuid is used to return the XUID of my personal Xbox account that I have linked to the API.

Comment: oh yes - I now see in the docs the endpoint. Using `https://xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/Major%20Nelson` gave me an error regarding `No API Key provided or invalid API Key`

Comment: @RamRaider Yes.. Which is why I provide the X-Auth key in the header, like the documentation states to do for Messages and Activity Feed. In the code above I have `InsertAuthCodeHere` but when I actually run it, I provide my authentication key.

Comment: I signed up so I could test but I would need an XBox Live account too - my point though was using the url you initially used gave a 302 but the one I tried last merely required authorisation headers ( which I couldn't give ) so perhaps try using `https://xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/` as the endpoint rather than `http://www.xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/`..... good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `xuid` with your actual xbox profile user id.
Additionally replace `InsertAuthCodeHere` with your API auth code.
You can find both on your xboxapi account profile after logging into xbox live.

See: https://xboxapi.com/v2/2533274813081462/xboxonegames

---

**Update - Guzzle**

I was able to get it working with [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/overview.html), works with `http` or `https`

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php'; //defines XboxAPI_Key
$gamertag = isset($_GET['gamertag']) ? urldecode($_GET['gamertag']) : 'Major Nelson';
$url = 'http://xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/' . rawurlencode($gamertag);
$guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $guzzle->get($url, [
    'headers' => [
        'X-Auth' => XboxAPI_Key,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
]);
echo $response->getBody(); //2584878536129841
```

---

**Update 2 - cURL**

The issue is related to validating the SSL certificate via `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` and the redirect from `http://www.` to `https://` occurring which is enabled with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
$gamertag = isset($_GET['gamertag']) ? urldecode($_GET['gamertag']) : 'Major Nelson';
$url = 'http://www.xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/' . rawurlencode($gamertag);
/**
 * proper url for no redirects
 * $url = 'https://xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/' . rawurlencode($gamertag);
 */
$options = [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return variable
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referrer on redirect
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //do not verify SSL cert
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'X-Auth: ' . XboxAPI_Key
    ]
]; 
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;  //2584878536129841
```

Comment: I am trying to get the XUID of users when I only know their gamertag.

Comment: Got ya, then you'll need to replace `InsertAuthCodeHere` with your API key from your profile.

Comment: I have. I just removed it from the post to keep it private.

Comment: Since this is for a XenForo add-on, on a web host that I have no control of, I do not think I can use Guzzle. Unless I misunderstand.

Comment: Unsure of the scope of XenForo or how you would deploy your application with it. I am looking into the specific issue with your cUrl request, as not much should change beyond `Guzzle` and `cUrl`

Comment: I have no access to install/use guzzle on my shared host. EDIT: Sorry, can you install guzzle and use it through FTP? I really don't know anything about it or how to use it.

Comment: Guzzle is just a 3rd party PHP  library, `composer.phar` would be the one that would be difficult to install and update your dependencies.

Comment: I can't recreate this.. Keep getting an error: `E_WARNING : type 2 -- curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set -- at line 14`

Comment: Change the URL to the one in the commented out code to avoid the redirects. `https://xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/` then remove the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ` line. Otherwise see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918623/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated

Comment: Additionally you may be able to do `ini_set('open_basedir', null);` before the curl call. since `open_basedir` is changeable via `PHP_INI_ALL`

Comment: I changed the url to `https://www.xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/`, removed the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, and added `ini_set('open_basedir', null);` before the curl execution. I get the following: `You input disabled function(s) by PhpFiddle : ini_set('open_basedir', null)`. Without setting `open_basedir` I get the same "Moved Permanently" error.

Comment: Look at the comment in my answer and comment I proved earlier, you need to exclude `www.` from the URL The issue with using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` was due to `open_basedir` being defined, which looks like is protected by `PhpFiddle`, so you can't use the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to fix the redirecting of the API.

Comment: In the other stackoverflow question I linked in my comment, there are answers that provide a solution to hunting for the resulting URL after the redirects, but seems more appropriate to set the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. We were missing required curly braces. Working code:

```
$gamertag = rawurlencode("Major Nelson");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xboxapi.com/v2/xuid/{$gamertag}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "X-Auth: InsertAuthCode",
]);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print $output;
```

Comment: The curly brackets will not affect the result of the url. The URL without `www.`... was your issue, as I noted in my answer. EG: `"a" . $gamertag` is the same as `"a$gamertag"` is the same as `"a{$gamertag}"`  See: http://ideone.com/rNeinC