# Official XBOX Live API?

Tags: php, xbox, xbox-live

I have been searching for a while now on how to access user data from XBOX live.

Unfortunately, all I found was [this](https://xboxapi.com) which only allows 2 API calls per minute.

Is there an *offcial* XBOX API that I can access for user information ?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603905/how-to-interact-with-xbox-api-using-php-and-curl) SO question could help you to clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey as the owner and Developer of XboxAPI, I can tell you that the old v1 is discontinued. With regards to the latest version of the API (v2) this doesn't limit you to 2 requests per minute, its requests per hour depending on your subscription. Here are the hourly limits and costs per subscription.

- Free (£0 per year - 120 API requests per hour)
- Silver (£2 per month - 400 API requests per hour)
- Gold (£5 per month - 1,000 API requests per hour)
- Platinum (£10 per month - 3,000 API requests per hour)
- Titanium (£40 per month - 20,000 API requests per hour)
- Uber (£100 per month - 50,000 API requests per hour)

XboxAPI runs off of an official API that powers the desktop and mobile applications. The reason that I created this API is because its not very user accessible.

If you wish to get the official API yourself, then you need to be a member of ID@Xbox and this is for Indi Game Developers only who are already established, and wish to launch on the Xbox console.

Comment: Every time I try to use your API it just says "A new login is required to get fresh access tokens" even though I'm logged into your webpage and can see my auth id.  I don't see documentation anywhere on your site as to what this means.

Comment: In that xboxapi, you are asking to send x-auth and xuid for some endpoints. If I want other users data, I need their xbox profile user id. How to get these or How to implement sign in with xbox outh as in your website to get the xbox profile user id?

Comment: @Gargoyle I ran into this as well. If you click the `Remember Me` checkbox in the window after clicking `Sign in to Xbox LIVE` you get some more info about how it works. It seems like if you want it to automatically refresh your api token (not the XboxApi API Key) you'll need it to save your password.

Answer (score 6):

As for the official API, at GDC we just announced the Xbox Live Creators Program, which will soon be open to all developers via the Xbox Live Creators Program – no concept approval required! You will be able to rapidly publish your game to Xbox One or Windows 10 through a short and simplified certification process.

To get started, go here:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/xboxlive/creator
and follow the 4 steps and it'll guide you through the process.

There's more information here about all our GDC announcements at 
https://majornelson.com/2017/03/01/new-investments-for-xbox-developers-and-gamers-kick-off-gdc-2017/

Comment: What about for mobile application developers that have game related apps and want gamer tag information?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to @Marquis103's question as well.

Comment: Currently for the Xbox Live Creators Program, we only support Xbox One console and Windows 10 PC.  Thanks

Comment: Looks like the link results in a 404 in 2023. Can we get it updated?

Answer (score 0):

API Rate Limits
Xbox does not provide an official API for anyone to use. Their are a few sites that provide an API one of which is https://xboxapi.com/v1 xboxapi makes it very easy to pull your Xbox API data.

i found some hint this will enable the page to load faster and avoid going over xboxapi's API Limit which is set to 350 requests an hour.

https://daveismyname.com/blog/display-xbox-live-data-with-xboxapi-and-cache-it

checck this out

Comment: Is there any way *not* to use xboxapi.com ?

Comment: The v1 of the API was discontinued a long time ago, you can now only use the latest version of v2.

Comment: @HittmanA Not really no, I am the only API site that I know of offering this information to the public for free