# Replace whateverorigin.org call with local proxy in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ssl

I'm currently using whateverorigin.org in some javascript to retrieve a URL as a JSON object because a 3rd party site hasn't made one of their functions available via their JSON API.

I'd like to remove this dependancy from my website as whateverorigin.org breaks the HTTPS/SSL browser checks for secure content because it's a clear http call.

Has anyone done this? I haven't found an example of it anywhere.

Thanks in advance for a response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so since I first typed up this question, I've now already found some examples and cobbled together a working proxy function in php... Feel free to use it for your own purposes!

```
<?php
// Sourced from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511410/curl-follow-location-error
function curl_exec_follow(/*resource*/ &$ch, /*int*/ $redirects = 20,     /*bool*/ $curlopt_header = false) {
    if ((!ini_get('open_basedir') && !ini_get('safe_mode')) || $redirects < 1) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $curlopt_header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $redirects > 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $redirects);
        return curl_exec($ch);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);

        do {
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch))
                break;
            $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if ($code != 301 && $code != 302)
                break;
            $header_start = strpos($data, "\r\n")+2;
            $headers = substr($data, $header_start, strpos($data,"\r\n\r\n", $header_start)+2-$header_start);
            if (!preg_match("!\r\n(?:Location|URI): *(.*?) *\r\n!",$headers, $matches))
                break;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $matches[1]);
        } while (--$redirects);
        if (!$redirects)
           trigger_error('Too many redirects. When following redirects, libcurl hit the maximum amount.', E_USER_WARNING);
        if (!$curlopt_header)
            $data = substr($data, strpos($data, "\r\n\r\n")+4);
        return $data;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$retrieveurl = curl_init(urldecode($_GET['url']));
$callbackname = $_GET['callback'];

$htmldata = curl_exec_follow($retrieveurl);

if (curl_error($retrieveurl))
    die(curl_error($retrieveurl));

$status = curl_getinfo($retrieveurl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($retrieveurl);

$data = array('contents' => $htmldata, 'status' => $status);

$jsonresult = json_encode($data);

echo $callbackname . '(' . $jsonresult . ')';

?>
```

Hope this helps someone!