# PHP: cURL: Login and download file - CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION issue

Tags: php, csv, curl, authentication

I'm trying to login into a website and then downloading a .csv file using cUrl. I have open_basedir set to my web dir.

The problem is that when i run my code i get this error:

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set

So im trying to find an alternative to this and searching around i found this: [curl follow location error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511410/curl-follow-location-error) but that doesnt help me.

What happens (according to some output set around the code) is that i get a first 302 (which is the login redirect to the **secure area home page**) and then when i try to ask for the .csv it looks like that i'm not logged in.

I tested the code in my local env (with followlocation enabled and working) and everything works just fine. I tried to manually handle the response code and if 302 is found force a new curl call on the **secure area home page** but even so it doesn't work when i try to get the file.

Hope this was clear enought...