# i can't fix this 'when safe_mode is enabled"

Tags: web-services

This is the error I'm getting for [this website](http://winecoolerlist.com).

> "Message: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl follow location error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511410/curl-follow-location-error)

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you need to go into your php config (maybe */etc/php.ini*) and

- set `safe_mode = Off`, and
- unset `open_basedir` value.

This is disabling some security, so know what you are doing...