# curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set

Tags: php, curl, hosting, open-basedir

I am using `.php` files to send `OTP` messages for my app. When I hosted these files on my local machine, everything worked fine. Now,
I have hosted these files on [hostinger](http://www.hostinger.com), when I call one of these files I get a response saying

```
curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir 
   is set in /home/u5050****/public_html/scbapp/smsauth/***sms-api.php on line 39
```

Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511410/curl-follow-location-error

Comment: @C0dekid.php I did read that but, I didnt get that. Maybe coz im still new to php.

Comment: @C0dekid.php I am actually an Android developer who just got hold of `php` for OTP purpose. So if it is as simple as changing `php.ini` file or something similar, I can do it, rest of the php is, unfortunately, out of my reach.

Comment: can you try this: Open your `php.ini` and look for the open_basedir line and comment it. Then save the file and restart your server. First check if `safe_mode` is `off`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CURLOPT\_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918623/curlopt-followlocation-cannot-be-activated)

Comment: @C0dekid.php I dont think it is the problem of safe mode. because the error should have mentioned otherwise. Unfortunately my host provider is not allowing me to access the `php.ini` file as of now.

Comment: And if you put at the beginning of your script, under `<?php` this code: `ini_set("open_basedir", "none")`

Comment: @C0dekid.php I am still getting that error. Hey, can I also set safe mode off like this from my php file?

Comment: @Poda Yeah, could you give it a try? Let me know what happend then. Give it the value "`off`"

Comment: @C0dekid.php I am also getting a new warning saying: `curl_setopt(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(cookie_way2sms) is not within the allowed path(s): (none) in /home/u5******15/public_html/s****p/smsauth/way2sms-api.php on line 38`

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to ask your host provider to turn of these if they want to. My solutions are empty for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl follow location error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511410/curl-follow-location-error)