# I use curl to parse url and get meta tags but CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION error occurs

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing, metadata

I want to get url meta data like title, description, keywords etc and everyone suggest curl is the best way to get what i need so i use curl.I use exactly this code

```
<?php
 function file_get_contents_curl($url)
 {
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

   @$data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   return $data;
 }

 $html = file_get_contents_curl("http://example.com/");

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 @$doc->loadHTML($html);
 $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
 $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
 $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

 for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
 {
   $meta = $metas->item($i);
   if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'Description')
    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
   if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'Keywords')
    $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
 }

 echo "Title: $title". '
  <br>
 ';
 echo "Description: $description". '
  <br>
 ';
 echo "Keywords: $keywords";
 ?>
```

and when i run this code this error occurs

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot   
be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set
```

How to solve this error to get meta tags or is there are better way or library to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl follow location error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511410/curl-follow-location-error)

Comment: refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511410/curl-follow-location-error).

Comment: safe mode is turned on so how to do it

Comment: is there any good library which can do this same